# Making menu wrapped in nav tag

Tags: blocks, hooks, navigation

I've got problem with making main-menu wrapped in  element.
I've tried:

1. Using hooks in template.php like:

   ```
   function koko_menu_link_main_menu($variables) { /* For block override */
   $output = '<nav>';
         foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
           $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
     }
     $output .= '</nav>';
     return $output;
   }


   function koko_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
     $output = '<nav>';
   foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
     $output .= l($link['title'], $link['href'], $link);
   }
     $output .= '</nav>';
       return $output;
   }
   ```

   Using preprocesss/block.preprocess.inc:

   ```
     switch ($variables['block']->module) {
       case 'system':
         switch ($variables['block']->delta) {
           case 'help':
           case 'powered-by':
             break;

         case 'main':
             // Use a template with no wrapper for the page's main content.
             $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__minimal';
             break;

         default:
             // Any other "system" block is a menu block and should use
             // block--nav.tpl.php
             $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__nav';
             break;
         }
         break;

         case 'menu':
         case 'menu_block':
         // Use block--nav.tpl.php template.
         $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__nav';
         break;
     }


   case 'main':
     // Use a template with no wrapper for the page's main content.
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__minimal';
     break;

   default:
     // Any other "system" block is a menu block and should use
     // block--nav.tpl.php
     $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__nav';
     break;
    }
    break;

   case 'menu':
   case 'menu_block':
       // Use block--nav.tpl.php template.
        $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'block__nav';
        break;
      }
   ```

That contains. block--nav.tpl.php

```
    <nav<?php print $attributes; ?>>
      <?php print render($title_prefix); ?>
      <?php print render($title_suffix); ?>
      <?php print $content; ?>
    </nav>
```

Still nothing happends. Main-menu is not wrapped in anything different than: `<div class="content">`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [this](https://drupal.org/node/2088267) and [this](https://drupal.org/node/1033442#comment-5076932) posts? I thinks it's not so difficult to achieve this:

```
function MYTHEME_links__system_main_menu($variables) {
  $html = "<div>\n";
  $html .= "  <nav>\n";
  foreach ($variables['links'] as $link) {
    $html .= "<li>".l($link['title'], $link['path'], $link)."</li>";
  }
  $html .= "  </nav>\n";
  $html .= "</div>\n";
  return $html;
}
```

Comment: Nothing happends. Even after copy&cut of your code (with changing `MYTHEME`) nothing happends. Cache cleared and CRON updated.